# Detecting the element clicked on

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with `tr`'s where you can click on.
These `tr`'s can contain `a`'s.

```
  <tr id="12" href="/guestbook/edit?id=12">
    <td class="main">
       <strong>Remi</strong>
       <a href="mailto:xxx@xxx">xxx@xxx</a>
    </td>
    <td class="date">05-11-2010 11:34</td>
    <td class="number">ip</td>
  </tr>
```

This is the jquery code to detect the click on the tr

```
$('table tr[href]').click(function(e){
   document.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

When I click on the e-mail address for example, first my e-mail client opens (which is good) and then the page edit loads (which is bad). Is it possible to detect the element I've clicked on? If it's an A or an TR?

Comment: dont use href on a tr, its evil (evil i tell you!), you can, for instance, use data-href (HTML5)

Comment: Ok, thanx, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: add different event listeners to A and TR, then you will know which is which. http://jsbin.com/uzivu3/edit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the [`.target` of the event](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and see what its [`.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName) is, like this:

```
$('table tr[href]').click(function(e){
   if(e.target.nodeName == 'A') return;
   document.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

---

As @[Hannes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353093/hannes) says in comments though, it's better to use at least a data attribute here, like this:

```
<tr id="12" data-href="/guestbook/edit?id=12">
```

Then in your code:

```
$(this).attr('data-href');
```

Or, in jQuery 1.4.3+:

```
$(this).data('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

When a click event happens, it first is triggered on the element you clicked, then propagated to parent elements, triggering their onclick handlers. You could do this in addititon to the code you have:

```
$('tr[href] a').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('tr[href]').trigger('click');
    return false;  // stop event propagation (email client won't be called)
});
```

But I'd recommend you to remove anchors from the edit and delete, because you deceive your user this way.